# Why Java Calendar store fields in an array instead of generic fields?

Tags: java, android

Okay so, as a new android dev, I discovered that (so far) only [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class that use array to store its fields, and create an integer constant to mark the index names. For example:

```
public class Calendar{
    ...
    public static final int ERA = 0;
    public static final int YEAR = 1;
    public static final int MONTH = 2;
    protected int[] fields = null;
    ...
}
```

And if you want to get, for example the year of the calendar:

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

What's the purpose of this kind of design? I mean, why not use something like:

```
public class Calendar{
    ...
    protected int year;
    ...
    public int getYear() { return year; }
}
```

And access it with usual getter method:

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().getYear();
```

What's the reason behind it?

Comment: You may want to check if Java is iterating over the fields. Only reason that comes to my mind.

Comment: Also only 1 get method instead of one per field.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @xenteros whoops sorry, just back on computer. i'll digest it for a while thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply `SOLID`, `Open-Close` to be strict. [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Imagine, one day someone in Oracle will decide to add nanoseconds to the `Calendar`. It'll be as easy as adding one cell to the `fields` and one field called NANOSECONDS. It's just a good design.

They won't need to change loops through all fields. No need of reflection.

Well, it's also `DRY` (Don't Repeat Yourself) instead of `WET` (We Enjoy Typing). Why would one type all of those getters and setters? It would mess the code and make it not readable. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

As [dit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1614378/dit) pointed out:

It was also useful when designing `add` method. Now you only point a field and the value you want to add instead of using appropriate methods from `{addYear, addMonth etc.}`. It would be veery `WET` in terms of Waste Everyones Time.

Now you can simply use:

```
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
```

which will change the year to the next one.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) - for those who aren't familier with SOLID.

Comment: @MordechayS Poor they...

Comment: wow it's crazy clever. i wonder why would no one in college taught me that.

Comment: so, why not every java class use that design instead?

Answer (score 0):

it is also easy to change the date. for example increment the fields:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1); // one year later
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // tomorrow
```

Imagine what we should do without the software design described by [xenteros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39909906/1614378).